# Windows 7 doesn't show in GRUB menu

Tags: dual-boot, os-prober

I have dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows 7. I needed to reinstall W7 and after that I reinstalled grub so that I could access both Ubuntu and W7.

Unfortunately my GRUB menu doesn't show W7. I tried `update-grub`, I also tried `os_prober` and then `update-grub`. I also tried boot-repair, but none of these seemed to work. Here is my bootinfoscript output:

http://pastebin.com/QD8Bx0jQ

Comment: what was the output of `sudo os-prober`?

Comment: You could repair your Windows boot first with a Win7 recovery DVD (it will rewrite MBR & remove GRUB), THEN do boot repair.

Comment: It does not look like os-prober ran? Did you delete 30_os-prober? And you have an awful lot of kernels, your grub may have more entries if you scroll down, but it does not look like it has a Windows entry at the bottom. Do you have a really tiny arrow at the bottom right corner of the grub box that the menu is in?

Comment: please see my solution in the post https://askubuntu.com/questions/448040/os-prober-and-update-grub-cant-see-find-working-windows-install/978688#978688

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the script lines from the os_prober are not inserted in the grub script file at all. Maybe there is an error in the file:

```
/etc/grub.d/30_os_prober
```

It normally should show itself even if no other os is detected. You could purge grub-common and reinstall it, but maybe it is more safe to download [grub-common.deb](http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/grub2/grub-common_2.00-19ubuntu2_i386.deb) and just take the file from there.
If you run

```
sudo grub-mkconfig | grep prober
```

you should see the script beginning and ending. If this is not working no matter if your windows boot works or not, it will not show up.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was really with `os_prober`. Some time ago I was messing with grub configuration and I moved file `30_os_prober` in the `grub.d` directory to another location and I don't even remember why I did so.

After moving it back to its rightful place and running 
`sudo grub-mkconfig` and then `sudo update-grub` it works fine :)

Thank you all for your responses!! It was very helpful!!

Comment: Always good to have a clean cause and a clean solution. Enjoy Ubuntu..